# @Secured annotations work but @PostAuthorize with PermissionEvaluator doesn't

Tags: spring, spring-security

The following problem has been driving me insane:

I have the following setup:

- interface StudyService
- @Service StudyServiceImpl implements StudyService
- @Controller StudyServiceController implements StudyService
- SampleDAOImpl implements SampleDAO
- A permissionEvaluator CdmPermissionEvaluator

I have the following code:

```
class SampleDAOImpl implements SampleDAO {
...
    @Secured(Roles.USER)
    @PostAuthorize("hasPermission(returnObject, 'read')")
    Sample load(long sampleId) {
        ...
    }
...
}
```

The @Secured works, as I have to log in when that is present. However, the @PostAutorize doesn't work, even when I comment out the @Secured. I have a logging statement in CdmPermissionEvaluator.hasPermission(), and it never gets logged. This is also the case when I comment out the @Secured annotation (to avoid that the @PostAuthorize doesn't get evaluated because of the default AffirmativeBased voter).

Relevant parts of web.xml:

```
...
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
...
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.rpc</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
...
```

Relevant parts of spring-servlet.xml:

```
...
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>
<context:annotation-config/>

<!-- Auto-detect controllers; these extend RemoteServiceServlet and are -->
<!-- annotated with @Controller -->
<context:component-scan base-package="org.gmeb.crf.server">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation"
                expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>
...
```

Relevant parts of applicationContext.xml:

```
<context:annotation-config/>

<bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="org.gmeb.crf">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation"
                expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

Relevant parts of applicationContext-security.xml:

```
<http auto-config="true" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint"
      create-session="always" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll()"/>
    <form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
                authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"/>
    <logout success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler"/>
    <anonymous/>
</http>
...
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"> <!-- TODO: Add proxy-target-class="true" -->
    <expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
</global-method-security>

<beans:bean id="expressionHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <beans:property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="cdmPermissionEvaluator"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="loggerListener"
            class="org.springframework.security.authentication.event.LoggerListener"/>

<context:annotation-config/>

<beans:bean id="cdmPermissionEvaluator" class="org.gmeb.crf.server.auth.CdmPermissionEvaluator">
</beans:bean>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Before I had this setup I had @PostAuthorize annotations with Spring EL expressions (no permissionEvaluator) in @Service StudyServiceImpl, and that worked. So what am I doing wrong, and what's the difference with the previous setup?

Thanks in advance,

Arnaud

Comment: After breaking my head over this for a couple of days, I found the problem: spring-servlet.xml had secured-annotations="enabled", but not pre-post-annotations="enabled". Changing that fixed my problem.. So if I understand correctly I could remove the <global-method-security> tag from applicationContext-security.xml, as it's really the one from spring-servlet.xml that is being used? Also, I load the @@Controllers in spring-servlet.xml and all the rest from applicationContext.xml. Can I also load @@Services from spring-servlet.xml and all the rest from applicationContext.xml instead?

Answer (score 2):

This won't work because you can't mix different annotation types on a single method without getting odd results. It's therefore recommended that you stick to a single "security metadata" option for each class or interface you want to secure.

In more detail, multiple different metadata sources (secured annotations, pre-post annotations, pointcut definitions, JSR-250 annotations) may be used in an application. They are all typically handled by a [`DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource`](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/access/method/DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource.java) instance which will only query its delegates until it gets a concrete answer from one of them. So if you have `@Secured` and `@PreAuthorize` defined for a method, only one will be used.

You should only have one `<global-method-security>` element defined in your app. You only need to place it in the `-servlet.xml` context file if you are applying method security to web controllers or other beans defined in there.